# Android: How to send R.String Data into SQLlite Database and retrieve it

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hi how to send the String value which is in **R.String.XXXX** into database, i tried as below but getting  address instead of  the actual string content.

In my class

```
 DatabaseHelper.getInstance(Aboutipc_fragment.this).addAboutData(R.string.aboutcontent, "haresh");
```

In my Database Helper class

```
public void addAboutData(int aboutcontent,String string) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        //System.out.println("geting notes from the database===== "+str);
        cv.put(KEY_ABOUTCONTENT, aboutcontent);
        cv.put(KEY_VALUE,string);
        db.insert(CREATE_ABOUTIPC_TABLE, null, cv);

    }
```

I am fetching Data As below

```
public Cursor fetchcontentvalues() {
        Cursor c = null;
         c = db.query(CREATE_ABOUTIPC_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ABOUTCONTENT}, null, null, null, null,null);
        //moving to the first note
        //c.moveToFirst();
         c.moveToPosition(0);
        System.out.println("getting notes from the database"+c.getString(0));

        return c;

    }
```

Output

```
getting notes from the database 2131099663
```

The system out statement is giving some address value i want to display the actual content of the string.

Comment: To get the `String` from a resource: `getResources().getString(R.string.aboutcontent)`, from an activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
String aboutContent = getResources().getString(R.string.xxxx);
```

Change your `addAboutData` method as below

```
 public void addAboutData(String aboutcontent,String string) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();


        cv.put(KEY_ABOUTCONTENT, aboutcontent);
        cv.put(KEY_VALUE,string);
        db.insert(CREATE_ABOUTIPC_TABLE, null, cv);

    }
```

Then fetch data using

```
public Cursor fetchcontentvalues() {
        Cursor c = null;
         c = db.query(CREATE_ABOUTIPC_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ABOUTCONTENT}, null, null, null, null,null);
        //moving to the first note
        //c.moveToFirst();
         c.moveToPosition(0);
        System.out.println("getting notes from the database"+c.getString(0));

        return c;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is very simple

get strings from r.string you can use method getString which return a String Value

```
String a=getString(R.string.name);
```

in your method you can use

```
addAboutData(getString(R.string.name), "haresh");
```